# Why do we need the variance term in SWAG method?

Tags: bayesian, posterior, bayesian-network, variational-bayes

My question is about the [SWA-Gaussian paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1902.02476.pdf).
I do not really understand why they need the 1/2 factor for the covariance matrix (as underlined in the picture). I understand that it is needed because both terms *diag* and *low-rank* basically contain variance so we don't want to overcount. But covariance terms only enter the *low-rank* term so multiplying it by 1/2 would mean undercounting them. Am I correct? To be honest, I don't understand why we need the *diag* term at all if the *low-rank* term contains both variance and covariance?

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: Hint: what does the footnote associated with the “4” say?

Comment: "We use one half as the scale here because both the diagonal and low rank terms include the variance of the
weights. We tested several other scales in Appendix D." Basically that they do it so they don't overcount variance.